# Product of counting measure and the integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Given the sigma algebra $P(\mathbb{N}^2)$(or $P(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ and counting measure $n$, I need to show that $n \times n$ is the counting measure for the aforementioned sigma algebra and compute the integral with respect to this measure for a given function.  I wanted to clarify something: the counting measure $n \times n$ is defined the same way as $n$ but for sets in $P(\mathbb{N}^2)$, correct?  What I'm not sure about is what the integral looks like.  I know that, given a measurable function $f:X \to \mathbb{C}$ and measure space $(X,M,n)$, $$\int_X f \text{dn} = \sum_{x \in X} f(x)$$

However, what about $\int \int f  \text{d(n $\times$ n)}$ for a measure space $(X \times Y, M \otimes N, n \times n)$? Does this integral have a similar closed form like the above?

Comment: Have a guess:
$$\sum_{x\in X}\sum_{y\in Y}f(x,y)\,.$$

Comment: @Berci That's what I expected, but I was worried about the order of the sums: the exercise is meant to show that Fubini fails for a function not in $L^1$.